C# Get object member polyline from a dynamic block
I have a custom dynamic block.  Using c# I am able to iterate all instances of the dynamic block, get property and attributes values, etc.  As part of the dynamic block there are labels and line objects.  I need to get the bounds of the block.  However, when I do so the extents of the block are including all the of other members, thereby making the block larger than what I am trying to achieve.
What I really need is to get the bound of a specific member of the dynamic block which is a polyline.  I cannot figure out how to navigate the block programmatically to get to that object.  Any help would be great appreciated.  Thank you in advance.  Here is my .dwg file: Link To DWG


In case anyone ends up facing the same challenge, someone from the Autodesk forum found the solution for me.  Here is the link to the solution: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/getting-the-extents-of-a-dynamic-block/td-p/12170940
